# Prove that $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is equicontinuous $K$ if $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is uniformly convergent on $K$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, equicontinuity

Suppose that for each positive integer $n$, $f_n$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$. I want to show that if some subset $K$ of $\Bbb{R}$, the sequence $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is uniformly convergent on $K$, then $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is equicontinuous $K$.

**MY TRAIL**

Let $f_i:K\to \Bbb{R},\;i=1,2,\cdots,\,N$ be continuous. Then, $\{f_i\}^{N}_{i=1}$ is uniformly continuous. Let $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $\delta_i>0$ such that $\forall \,x,y\in K$ with $\left|x-y\right|<\delta_i$, we have

\begin{align}\left|f_i(x)-f_i(y)\right|<\epsilon/3\end{align}
Take $\delta=\min\{\delta\}^{N}_{i=1}$. Then, $\forall \,x,y\in K$ with $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$, we have \begin{align}\left|f_i(x)-f_i(y)\right|<\epsilon/3,\forall\,i=1,\cdots,N\end{align}
which implies that $\{f_i\}^{N}_{i=1}$ is equicontinuous.

Since $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is uniformly convergent on $K$, then $\{f_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is uniformly Cauchy on $K$. So, there exists $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall\,m,n\geq N$
\begin{align}\left|f_n(x)-f_m(y)\right|<\epsilon/3\end{align}
In particular, for $m=N$,
\begin{align}\left|f_n(x)-f_N(y)\right|<\epsilon/3,\;\forall\,n\geq N\end{align}
Also, $\{f_i\}^{N}_{i=1}$ is equicontinuous, which implies that $f_N$ is is equicontinuous. So,
\begin{align}\left|f_N(x)-f_N(y)\right|<\epsilon/3,\;\text{whenever}\;\left|x-y\right|<\delta\end{align}
Hence, for $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$,
\begin{align}\left|f_n(x)-f_n(y)\right|&=\left|f_n(x)-f_N(x)+f_N(x)-f_N(y)+f_N(y)-f_n(y)\right|\\&\leq \left|f_n(x)-f_N(x)\right|+\left|f_N(x)-f_N(y)\right|+\left|f_N(y)-f_n(y)\right|\\&< \epsilon/3+\epsilon/3+\epsilon/3=\epsilon\end{align}

Please, I want you to help check if this is correct. Suggestions are highly welcome. If need be, an alternative proof will be highly appeciated if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: No, I was just wondering why you added in the $K$?

Comment: @copper.hat: Alright Sir!

Comment: @copper.hat: Kindly check! Is the proof correct?