# Does uniform continuity on a compact subset imply equicontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, equicontinuity

I gave a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913623/prove-that-f-n-infty-n-1-is-equicontinuous-k-if-f-n-infty?rq=1) some time ago but was wondering about the following:

Suppose that $f_n:K\subseteq \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous for each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, then $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly continuous. So, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$, there exists $\delta_n>0$ such that $\forall\,x,y\in K, \;|x − y| < \delta_n,$ implies
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon,\forall\;n\in \Bbb{N}.$$
Taking $\delta=\min\{\delta_n:\;n\in \Bbb{N}\}$ (which might not be true), then we have the definition given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079905/does-equicontinuity-imply-uniform-continuity), that
"for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall\,x,y\in K, \;|x − y| < \delta,$ implies
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon,\forall\;n\in \Bbb{N}.$$
which implies that $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous.

**QUESTION:** I'm I right? If not, can you please provide a counter-example?

Comment: What is the min of an infinite set of numbers?  What is $\min\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?  Your proof is flawed.

Comment: @RRL: Thanks for that! But how do I get an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions on a compact set that is not equicontinuous, select one that is pointwise but not uniformly convergent and with a discontinuous limit function.

An example is $f_n(x) = x^n$ with $K = [0,1]$. To see that these are not equicontinuous, suppose that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - 1| < \delta$ then $|f_n(x) - f_n(1)| =|x^n - 1| < 1/4$ for every $n$. However, since $x^n \to 0$ when $1- \delta < x < 1$, with $x$ fixed we can find  $n$ such that $|x^n - 1| > 1/4$ a contradiction.

Comment: So, a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions on a compact is cannot be regarded uniformly continuous, right?

Comment: If each function $f_n$ is continuous on compact $K$ then it is uniformly continuous, but the family $\{f_n\}$ may not be equicontinuous.

Comment: So, is it right to say that $f_n:K\subseteq \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous for each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, then $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly continuous. So, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$, there exists $\delta_n>0$ such that $\forall\,x,y\in K, \;|x − y| < \delta_n,$ implies
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon,\forall\;n\in \Bbb{N}?$$

Comment: Yes -- but it may not be the case that one $\delta$ works for every $f_n$.

Comment: "If each function fn is continuous on compact K then it is uniformly continuous, but the family {fn} may not be equicontinuous." Okay, I get you now!

Comment: Do you see why $\{x^n\}$ is not equicontinuous?  I can add that proof if you like.

Comment: Since the limit is not continuous, then it is not! But for future purposes, you can also add up the proof!

Comment: If $K$ contains at least two points, let $f_n(x)=nx.$