# Uniform continuous, equicontinuity, and Banach-Steinhaus

Tags: uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

Banach-Steinhaus is a sufficient condition for a family of operators to be equicontinuous.

Here, in [Does uniform continuity on a compact subset imply equicontinuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062492/does-uniform-continuity-on-a-compact-subset-imply-equicontinuity)

We have a function $f_n(x) = x^n$ on a compact set $K = [0,1]$ that is NOT equicontinuous. In this example, what assumptions of Banach-Steinhaus are violated?

Comment: What collection of linear operators are you talking about here?

Comment: @copper.hat The collection of linear operators in this context is just all the $f_n$'s where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Only $f_1$ is linear. The question does not make sense.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much. This makes sense.